# Why does assigning Infinity in JavaScript not throw an error, but not work?

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment, infinity

Why doesn't infinity give an error when attempted to be reassigned, but is not assignable?

```
var x = 3;

x = 1; // good, normal
true = 3; // error, normal

Infinity = 4; // no error

console.log(Infinity); // Infinity
```

Comment: Because `Infinity` is read-only, if' you'd use strict mode, and trying to declare a variable named Infinity, it would trigger an error.

Comment: Always use strict mode. Always.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity):

> Infinity is a **property** of the global object, or in other words, a variable **in global scope**.

Since it's a global property you can access it and assign any value. However assigning a value to a **non** Writable property doesn't raise any exception, *when you are in a **not** strict mode*, and doesn't change the value of the property.

If you use "strict mode", then an exception would be raised.

```js
"use strict"

Infinity = 4;
```

Comment: what about `Number` or `String`? neither of those generate an error in strict mode?

Comment: @SapphireBrick Indeed they don't generate an error. Both `Number` and `String` are "pointers" that point to the constructor function Number and the constructor function String. You could verify this, if you open a console and just write Number, then this would be the output:  _ƒ Number() { [native code] }_. For further info about this object please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number. Now try to do this `let a = new Number('5')` and then check this `a instanceof Number`, outputs `true`.

Comment: **If** you assign to Number the value of 4. You can do so...it's just a reference to an object. Then if you try this `let b = new Number('4)` you will get an error that says _VM802:1 Uncaught TypeError: Number is not a constructor
    at <anonymous>:1:5_ Essentially you have changed the reference that Number points to. That basically means that Number is a writable property. Unfortunately I haven't a link for this, but this is evident from the above. Side note: check the above code both in strict and non strict mode. You will not notice any difference.

Comment: The same holds true also for String. Hope that helps.